# In Delphi, should I care about Cyclomatic Complexity for "case of" statements?

Tags: delphi, switch-statement, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm using the built-in "Method Toxicity Metrics" in Delphi 10.3 in my code review flow and I have the following method:

```
function LoadTagsFromFile(const Filename: String; var Tags: TFileTags; var LastError: Integer): Boolean;
var
    AudioType: TAudioFormat;

begin
    AudioType := ExtToAudioType(ExtractFileExt(FileName));

    case AudioType of
        afApe: Result := LoadApeTags(Filename, Tags, LastError);

        afFlac: Result := LoadFlacTags(Filename, Tags, LastError);

        afMp3: Result := LoadMp3Tags(Filename, Tags, LastError);

        afMp4: Result := LoadMp4Tags(Filename, Tags, LastError);

        afOgg: Result := LoadOggTags(Filename, Tags, LastError);

        afWav: Result := LoadWavTags(Filename, Tags, LastError);

        afWma: Result := LoadWmaTags(Filename, Tags, LastError);

        else
            Result := LoadTags(Filename, Tags, LastError);
    end;
end;
```

Which is red flagged (CC = 8 making overall toxicity over 1) but I'm puzzled as how I could fix this specific case? Should I even care for this example?

Comment: Meh, probably wouldn't worry about it.  You could refactor to remove the case statement if it really bothers you.  Dictionary lookup for the correct method is probably the obvious solution - that removes the branch (ie: code is just fetch and execute - no conditions).  It also makes extension easier since you don't need to maintain this case statement that way - you just add new methods to the map.

Comment: @J... Can you provide an example (or link to one) as I don't remember doing that in Delphi. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, but it would be better put as a separate question.  At that, it really depends on what you didn't understand from my suggestion.  Do you know how to define a method type?  Do you know how to use a dictionary?  Are you familiar with method pointers?  Otherwise this will end up as a tutorial rather than a simple example...

Comment: @J.. Yes I know dicts, yes I understand method pointers but only used them in other languages (C++, JS...). Not sure about method type but I can search.

Comment: Ok, so the TKey for your dictionary would be a `TAudioFormat` and the TValue would be a `TLoadTagsFromFileMethod` where `TLoadTagsFromFileMethod = function(const Filename: String; var Tags: TFileTags; var LastError: Integer): Boolean;`.  This way to get the correct method you simply `Result := MyMethodDict[AudioType](Filename, Tags, LastError);` - no branching, see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not care at all for this example, IMHO. Firstly, the code in each case statement in clear and easy to read. Any other approach would make the code much more difficult to understand for no performance gain. i.e. you are reading a file from disk, you will never be able to measure any performance difference arising from any re-formulation of your case statement compared to the disk reading process.

Also, since you are using Delphi 10.3 you should take advantage of record helpers. I would make a

```
TAudioFormatHelper = record helper for TAudioFormat
 private
   function LoadApeTags(Filename, Tags, LastError):boolean; 
   ... other Load functions here...
 public 
    procedure LoadTagsFromFile(const Filename: String; var Tags: TFileTags; var LastError: Integer): Boolean;
    procedure SetFromFileName(const FileName:string)     

end
```

That way you get away from these global type methods and tie them to your enum.

i.e.

```
var
  audioFormat:TAudioFormat;
begin
  audioFormat.SetFromFileName(.....)
  audioFormat.LoadTagsFromFIle(.....)
```

of course, LoadTagsFromFile could set the audioFormat enum as well, but that is a different story. I am just going with our design that you set the enum value based on extension first.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on record helpers. I did not knew about them and refactored my whole unit to use them. Much better that way! Thanks!